# How does cs register work in protected mode?

Tags: x86, operating-system, protected-mode

This is the content of segment register, which is composed of 13-bit offset, 1-bit table indicator, and 2-bit requested privilege level:

```
Bit:     | 15                                3 | 2  | 1 0 |
Content: | offset (index)                      | ti | rpl |
```

This is a code snippet for initializing `ds` register:

```
.set PROT_MODE_DSEG,  0x10
movw $PROT_MODE_DSEG, %ax
movw %ax, %ds
```

This is the lowest 32 bits of an entry in Interrupt Descriptor Table(IDT):

```
Bit:     | 31              16 | 15              0 |
Content: | segment selector   | offset low        |
```

My question is:

1. When we set `ds` like above, we only set the 13-bit offset in `ds` register? If so, what does computer do to the other 3 bits(ti and rpl)?
2. Why the segment selector in IDT is 16 bits? As far as I understand, this segment selector is used as index into GDT. Shouldn't it be 13 bits like the offset in `ds`?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it sets the full 16 bits.
2. The full 16 bits are loaded into CS. The RPL is used in permission
   checks. The code segment descriptor for the interrupt handler may
   reside in either the GDT or the LDT.

Comment: But only 13 bits of the 16 bits segment register are offset. How can we set the full 16 bits by 13 bits offset?

Comment: For example, in the second diagram, I set `ds` register to 0x10. 0x10 is the offset of the third descriptor. From the first diagram the offset is only 13 bits. Does it mean 0x10 be stored in the 13 bits of the `ds` register?

Comment: No, 0x10 is the full 16-bit value to be loaded into DS. RPL is 0 and TI is 0.

Comment: Do you mean the structure displayed in the first diagram is wrong?

Comment: If not, could you please explain why there is a 13 bits offset in the `ds` register.

Comment: There are three fields in a segment register. Each time the register is loaded, all three fields are loaded. All three fields are required and used in permission checks.

Comment: But you still didn't explain the 13 bits offset, that's where I am confused.

Comment: @Bicheng : think of it this way. The 3 lower bits that are the privilege level and whether it is a GDT or LDT entry are read by the processor and the correct table is used (GDT/LDT) to find the correct entry in the corresponding table. The privilege level is checked for permissions. If the change is allowed then the processor zeroes the lower 3 bits and the result of that is the offset in the correct description table (LDT or GDT)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've got it. Because entries in GDT are all 8 bytes, so their offset would be like 0x8, 0x10 etc, which means the lowest three bits of their offset are always 000 and do not have to acctually take storage space. When we set a segment register, we only need highest 13 bits to store the value. When use the segment register to index GDT, we multiply the highest 13 bits by 8 or in your words "zeros the lower 3 bits". Am I correct?